# JSON is it best practice to give each element in an array an id attribute?

Tags: json

Is it best practice in JSON to give objects in an array an id similar to below?. Im trying to decide on a JSON format for a restful service im implementing and decide include it or not... If it is to be modified by CRUD operations is it a good idea?

```
{
  "tables": [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "tablename": "Table1",
       "columns": [
          {
            "name": "Col1",
            "data": "-5767703747778052096"
          },
          {
            "name": "Col2",
            "data": "-5803732544797016064"
          }
        ]
     },
     {
       "id": 2,
       "tablename": "Table2",
       "columns": [
        {
          "name": "Col1",
          "data": "-333333"
        },
        {
          "name": "Col2",
          "data": "-44444"
        }
     ]
  }
]
 }
```

Comment: It looks like you possibly have another unique ID already, `tablename`. If that truly is unique, you could go with that. The need for unique IDs is really determined by the application. Is it necessary for your application?

Comment: well i need a unique identifier alright.... i was just wondering if having an id field was the standard.... so in my example above i would avoid having the table name in any http request

Answer (score 1):

> Client-Generated IDs
>
> A server MAY accept a client-generated ID along with a request to
>   create a resource. An ID MUST be specified with an "id" key, the value
>   of which MUST be a universally unique identifier. The client SHOULD
>   use a properly generated and formatted UUID as described in RFC 4122
>   [RFC4122].

[jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org/)

Comment: This is referring to client-generated IDs being accepted by servers. The OP's question is about the server assigning IDs.